# How to fetch distinct Data for the When Statement inside the Case Condition in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I just  need distinct data but not on the **"SELECT"** statement but on for my **"case"** condition.

Okay This is the sql code:

```
select
 case 
  when length(b.level0_iid) = 4 then 'COMPANY'
  when length(b.level0_iid) = 7 and b.level0_iid like 'P%' then 'DIVISION'
  else 'Error'
 end "LEVEL 0"     
from Transact.et_travel_transaction a,
Transact.cy_2elist b
```

The problem with this code: `when length(b.level0_iid) = 4 then 'COMPANY'` is that `b.level0_iid` returns more than one data, but I just need one for my "case". I assumed that all the data therein are valid for condition, anyway if it's not, then there's no problem.  I have already tried to do `when length(first(b.level0_iid)) = 4 then 'COMPANY'` but the error states that: ORA-00904: "FIRST": invalid identifier.

As much as possible, I don't want to use subquery 'coz if I do, my codes would run hundreds of lines. If there's no other way than to do subquery, then that would be my last resort.

Is my requirement possible?  Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand, do you need [DISTINCT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#sthref9763) values ?

Comment: yes i need distinct value, but not in the "**SELECT**" statement but in the **WHEN** statement inside the **"CASE"**.

Comment: Lets assume you have 4 records with length of 4 and 5 with length of 7 you want to have one record with 'COMPANY' and one with 'DIVISION', right?

Comment: right, and that is to be used in my when statement. is it possible?

Comment: Do you have other columns in your select clause? otherwise a simple `distinct` should do...

Comment: yes I have other columns, i also tried putting distinct, but the error is ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

Comment: So which one of the values (in the other columns) would you like to view ? can you provide some data sample and desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an aggregation of some sort.  Here is an attempt to show what to do.  The case statement counts the number of rows that match each condition, to choose between the possibilities:

```
select <all other columns here>,
       (case when sum(case when length(b.level0_iid) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'COMPANY'
             when sum(length(b.level0_iid) = 7 and b.level0_iid like 'P%') > 0
             then 'DIVISION'
             else 'Error'
        end) as "LEVEL 0"
from Transact.et_travel_transaction a join
     Transact.cy_2elist b
     on <proper join conditions here
group by <all other columns here>
```

You could use `first`, in a similar way to your original query:

```
select <all other columns here>,
       (case when first(length(b.level0_iid)) = 4
             then 'COMPANY'
             when first(length(b.level0_iid)) = 7 and first(b.level0_iid like) 'P%')
             then 'DIVISION'
             else 'Error'
        end) as "LEVEL 0"
from Transact.et_travel_transaction a join
     Transact.cy_2elist b
     on <proper join conditions here
group by <all other columns here>
```